# Is there a possibility to extract sessions from mixpanel

Tags: mixpanel

I can export all events from API, but they have something called sessions which are virtual events they compute based on events I send, is there a possibility to get those sessions like session start and session end.

I tried JQL and data export but only sent events was shown.